# Translating pseudocode for the Jacobi algorithm into Mathematica

Tags: numerics, procedural-programming, homework

Here is an image for the Jacobi algorithm. I have almost no knowledge of Mathematica, the textbook does not help. Does not provide examples. The class average is 64%.

I just want to be able to complete my homework. I want to understand how one translate pseudocode properly into Mathematica. I have to use this pseudocode. Here is what I currently have based on my interpretation of the image. I'm following it as strictly as possible. It does not work for Steps 1-4 and I want to know why.

[image]

```
n = 50;
a = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0.5, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 0.25}, {50, 50}];
b = SparseArray[{{i_} -> 1/i}, {50}];
X0 = SparseArray[{{i_} -> 1}, {50}];
MaxN = 500;
TOL = 10^(-5);
k = 1
While[k <= MaxN, 
 For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  XI = (1/a[[i, i]])*(b[[i]] - 
      Sum[If[j != i, a[[i, j], 0]*X0[[j]]], j = 1, n]);
  If [Norm[XI - X0] < TOL, Print[XI], Break[]]]]
```

Comment: Ooof. Look, you are not helping your case by [deleting your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224570/27951) that had been downvoted and was probably going to be closed, then re-posting a new identical one, in which you proceed to *blame it on your instructor*.

Comment: The person asked for me to place my code and be specific.

Comment: Have you tried to search this site for the keywords "Jacobi algorithm"? I know from a very reliable source that there _is_ an implementation of the algorithm on this site... ;) General hint: You really don't want to use `For` loops in step 3 and 6. For example, step 3 is just `XI = (b- a.X0)/diag`, where `diag = Normal[Diagonal[a]]`, and step 5 it just `X0=XI`. Btw., the pseudocode is maybe not ideal, but it is also not bad, either. So please, don't blame it on the instructor.

Comment: As for the return value: You need to have the `Break[]` and the return in the same part of the `If` statement. So something like `If [Norm[XI - X0] < TOL, return=XI; Break[];]` would be more appropriate (note the `;` instead of your `,`).

Comment: I'd suggest `Return[XI, While]` instead of `Print[XI]`.  And look up the syntax of `Sum` in the docs.

Comment: What goes wrong when you execute the code? (Indicating that is part of "be[ing] specific".) There appears to be a bracket mismatch, for one thing.

Comment: Just posted a new code after modification, I also noticed the bracket mismatched and fixed that. I think the main problem is the formula I was given.

Comment: Check documentation for `Sum` to correct syntax there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, you have several issues in your code, most of which are easily solved with some basic understanding of Mathematica's syntax and a sharp eye:

- Your closing brackets are all in the end of your code, you should pay attention to where the for-loop should end and where it actually does end.
- As Henrik mentioned: You need to check the syntax of the `If` statement:

```
 If[condition,
 action if condition is evaluated to true,
 action if condition is evaluated to false
 ]
```

As you can see, the comma is used to seperate between the condition, the action and the "else" action. The semicolon is used to seperate several commands within each action part.

- As Michael mentioned, you need to check the syntax of `Sum`. (speaking from my own experience, the syntax of Mathematica takes some getting used to, especially when coming from a language like c++. )
- You haven't coded steps 5 and 6, so of course you will not get the desired result.

Since I personally learn best from existing, working code - here is a corrected version of your attempt:

```
 n = 50; 
 a = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1, {i_, j_} /; 
 Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 0.25}, {n, n}]; 
 b = SparseArray[{{i_} -> 1/i}, {n}]; 
 X0 = SparseArray[{{i_} -> 1}, {n}]; 
 X = X0; MaxN = 50; TOL = 10^(-1); 
 k =1; 
 While[k <= MaxN, 
  (*Step 3*) 
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    X[[i]] =(1/a[[i, i]])*(b[[i]] - Sum[If[j != i, a[[i, j]] X0[[j]], 0], {j, 1, n}]);
  ];
  (*Step 4*)
  If[Norm[X - X0] <= TOL,
   Print[Normal[X]];   Break[],
   If[k == MaxN,
     Print["Maximum number of iterations exceeded"]]
   ];
  (*Step 5*)
  k++;
  (*Step 6*)
  X0 = X;
 ]
```

For comparison, I also implemented some of the suggestions above:

```
n = 50;
a = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 
     0.25}, {n, n}];
b = SparseArray[{{i_} -> 1/i}, {n}];
X0 = SparseArray[{{i_} -> 1}, {n}];
diagSparse = Diagonal[a];
diag = Normal[Diagonal[a]];
X = X0;
MaxN = 50;
TOL = 10^(-1);
k = 1;
While[k <= MaxN,
 (*Step 3*)
 X = (b - a.X0 + diag X0)/diag;
 (*Step 4*)
 If[Norm[X - X0] <= TOL,
  Print[Normal[X]];
  Break[],
  If[k == MaxN, Print["Maximum number of iterations exceeded"]]
  ];
 (*Step 5*)
 k++;
 (*Step 6*)
 X0 = X;
 ]
```

The difference lies in the handling of the vectors and matrix, for which Mathematica has many useful functionalities. Again: Read the documentation, it explains these things really well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and I also read the documentation. My issue is when I read the documentation, its has simplified examples and I'm still trying to get familiar.  I'm going to try first writing notes on paper before coding. I'm going to keep this bookmarked so I can keep your tips for other formulas I will need to do. I notice that my issue was the matrix implementation. I'm still confused about the summation formula.